# How would you have multiple rewrite rules in htaccess with different patterns?

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, web

Ok I have a .htaccess file I'm working on for a framework design, I've been searching online and experimenting for three days with it and I'm getting a bit irritated.

Here's my convention:

Case 1: www.example.com/id

Case 2: www.example.com/key/id

What I want to do is make it easy for url managment, for case one I would use that to collect the page name, in case to it would be more like if someone had a store which would act as a key and tell the system to look for a store with the id of the given ID. I hope this gave more clarification.

Here's my htaccess definition:

**RewriteEngine On**

RewriteRule ^(A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/(.*)/?$ index.php?key=$1&id=$2

RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/?$ index.php?id=$1

Can someone please tell me why this isn't working or how I can get this to work?

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?dumpthis=$1 [L]
```

to see what's being rewritten there. You might need [L] at the end or RewriteBase or something else might be wrong. Post value of

```
$_GET['dump this']
```

if you need more help.

Comment: When I added that it gave me "index.php"

Comment: yeah, and you need to dump that GET argument to see the result of your rewrite. Then you gradually enhance your regexp to limit it only to what you need.